# What does the 66 in "66:PUSH 08" stand for?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, portable-executable, disassembly

Test platform is windows 32bit.

I use IDA pro to disassemble a PE file, do some very tedious transform work, and re-assembly it into a new PE file.

But there is some difference in the re-assembled PE file and the original one if I use OllyDbg
to debug the new PE file (although there is no difference of this part in the assembly file I transformed)

Here is part of the original one:
[image]

See the

```
PUSH 8 
PUSH 0
```

is correct.

Here is part of my new PE file:

[image]

See now the

```
PUSH 8
PUSH 0
```

is changed to

```
66:6A 08
66:6A 00
```

and it lead to the failure of the new PE's execution.

Basically, from what I have seen, it lead to the **un-align** of stack.

So does anyone know what is wrong with this part? I don't see any difference in the assembly code I transform....

Could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like the 32-bit version of the OpCode. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291151/how-push-imm-encodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

66h is the *operand-size override prefix*. In 32-bit code, it switches the *operand size* to 16-bit from the default 32-bit. So what happens here is that the `PUSH` instruction pushes a 16-bit value on the stack instead of the 32-bit one, and the `ESP` is decremented by 2 instead of 4. That's why you get unbalanced stack after the call.

You should check your assembler's documentation to see how you can force 32-bit operand size for the `PUSH imm` instructions. Different assemblers use different conventions for that. For example, in NASM you'd probably use something like `push dword 8`.

Comment: Does it really decrement ESP by 2, not 4?  I didn't think the x86-32 architecture would allow one to do that; what happens if the machine takes an interrupt at that moment?

Comment: @Igor, Thank you! I found there is a problem in my transformation code and fix it!

Answer (score 4):

It is a "prefix" opcode byte: See http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Legacy_Prefixes

0x66 means "operand size override".  Your code is apparantly operating in 32-bit mode; PUSH  without the prefix will push a 32 bit value.   I think what this does is cause the PUSH to fetch a *16* bit value, and push that as a 32 bit value on the stack. (I write a lot of assembly code, and have never had need to do that).